# PHP Post to a div on main html page - So it can be parsed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I have PHP code which successfully gets the contents of a directory on my server.

I wish to then write this array to a specific div on my main html page *(so that I can parse this later and use this information further)*

Currently my PHP navigates me away from my current page to write this array which I want to prevent.

Furthermore I wish to do all of the PHP work on a button click, and return the values on the main html page after.

How can I do this???

My button on my html page is as follows:

```
        <form action="PHP_Function.php">
        <input type="submit" class="learnButton" name="insert" value="Find Available Evidence" />                       
        </form>
```

And my PHP code looks like this to carry out the work:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
switch ($_POST['action']) {
    case 'insert':
        insert();
        break;

}}
```

I have an array: "*IfPresentArray*" which I then wish to write to my main html page:

```
if(in_array("Facebook.xml", $dirArray)){

    $IfPresentArray[0]="1";

    }else {

    $IfPresentArray[0]="0";
```

}

**Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to PHP.**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You need to use jQuery ajax to get the response from your php file (so you don't navigate away), then write the response on your `div` in the `success` setting of your ajax script http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (call that ajax function `on` your form submit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX techniques to do this. Use a Javascript framework like jQuery to react to the button click, make a request to your PHP script, and then update the contents of the div.

See http://api.jquery.com/click/ for handling clicks, and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for making the request.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an ajax call. This allows your to click some div, send something to the server, receive a response and display an output in many different formats.

You can either reference the jQuery library in your header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

or just download it and save it whereever

Here is a basic ajax call:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someval').click(function(){

      var content = $('#somecontenttoadd').val; //this could be many things... etc(.text, .html)


      $.ajax({                                      
              type:'post',
              url: 'PHP_Function.php',                     
              data: 'action='+content,                                                                     
              success: function(resp){

                $('#somediv').html(resp);   //lets put the information into a div
               //this could be anything response format like .val or .text instead of .html 


              },
              error: function(e){
                alert('Error: ' + e);
              }
            });

     });  

 });  

</script>
```

HTML -- you can get rid of the  tags and just use the id of the object.

```
<input type="submit" class="learnButton" name="insert" value="Find Available Evidence" id="someval"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, AJAX is the solution, I will give you the code that works for me, so that you have an exact starting point.

As I understand you have a separate html page and a php file that includes your function.

In order to make this work you will have to implement a function with an AJAX call.

This should be placed in a javascript file and will be invoked after the form submit button is clicked on the html page.

The AJAX call will then invoke your php function, get the response data back from php.

The javascript function will update the html page in the end.

You will need three files:

- main.html
- script.js
- function.php

Let me replace my original answer with a full example of the three files.

main.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class="container">
            <form id="myForm" method="post" action="function.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" form="myForm" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveButton">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div id="resultbox">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here we included jQuery, our own javascript and bootstrap just to look better. the form action is our function.php, the form 'id' is used in our jQuery code. the "result box" box will display the response.

script.js

```
$(function(){

  $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {

      $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {                 

                //display data...
                $("#resultbox").html(data.name).show; 

             }
           });

      return false;  
  });

});
```

this will override the default form submit behavior. I had a typo here in the original answer, I fixed it. url and data are taken from the html form, dataType is set to json, because we expect a json back.

function.php

```
<?php

    echo json_encode(array('name' => $_POST['name']));
```

Our php code is just one line, we build an array and return it as json. You can then used in jQuery, just like any other json, as shown in the above code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This really helps. The javascript and PHP code works great, however when the button is clicked I am still redirected to my PHP_Function.php page and the array is displayed there. 
I was wondering if I could prevent the PHP page from loading and present the array straight to a div within my main page.

Im a bit unsure of the **AJAX success** part?

Comment: I created an example from scratch, that is working as is. The original code was not working, because I made a mistake with the brakets in the JQery code, when I copied from my stuff, sorry about that.